# Capybara/Poltergeist, clicking on Hidden Checkbox?

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I have some HTML for a Checkbox im trying to click:

```
<td class="surface center">
<div class="checkbox-inline checkbox-inline--empty">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="stuff_check">
<input id="stuff_1" class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" name="stuff_1_checked" value="1" data-item="5">
<label class="optional" for="stuff_1">Checked</label>
</div>
</td>
```

When running a `page.find_by_id('id').trigger('click')` it does indeed work, just using `click` however it complains about Poltergeist possibly clicking another elements:

> Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
>          Firing a click at co-ordinates [-9468.5, 6] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector '' at this position. It may
>   be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you
>   don't care about overlapping elements, try using
>   node.trigger('click').

However I felt maybe this is because of it being set as "hidden", so I tried doing `page.find_by_id('ID', :visible => false).click` however it gave the same issue.

Any suggestions? Since I know using trigger.('click') isn't advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do a proper click on a hidden element because there would be no way for a user to click on an element that doesn't appear on the screen.
Your example is confusing because the hidden element doesn't have the same `name` attribute as the checkbox element which is what I would normally expect in this kind of setup.  Assuming that what you're really trying to do is check the "stuff_1" checkbox (and that is hidden via CSS) then you should be doing what a user of your app would have to do - click on the label.

```
page.find('label[for="stuff1"]').click
```

Comment: Unfortunately yeah the name is the same, but setup different with []'s instead of the number, ie stuff[1] etc... instead of stuff_1. Im a bit confused on the syntax however of your answer. what do the [ ]'s do? and is just the `'label` narrowing in on the area of the HTML?

Comment: It worked btw! Appreciate it. I guess my issue was that I was trying to click by the id...but I really should have been trying to click on the label itself.

Comment: It's a CSS selector, the []s specify a CSS attribute selector - you need to read up on CSS

Comment: So this is saying within the HTML for the 'label' picking specifically this CSS attribute. I

Comment: It's saying find a <label> element that has a `for` attribute equal to "stuff1" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
within('.checkbox-inline checkbox-inline--empty') do
  check('#stuff_1')
end
```

I really recommend using Pry to do this though as you'll save yourself a ton of pain finding which elements are where.

Comment: I've never heard of Pry, what exactly does it do for Automation? Also im not sure if that within would work, since there are multiples of these checkboxes all under the same class. Could I do some sort of within referring to the ID?

Comment: http://pryrepl.org/

Basically you add the gem to your gemfile, `bundle install`, then add `binding.pry` to the step definition you're working on and it stops the script at that point and lets you access debugging mode via command line.

It takes a little getting used to the commands, but you can paste variations of your step definition into the command line and at least see if page elements are found or not, which is a helpful way of writing tests without running them over and over.